# How to fix "value too large for defined data type" error when mounting volume to docker container

Tags: docker, volume, swarm, sshfs

I'm facing this error when i trying to mount a volume to docker container.

```
/propagated-mount/fc609e7d6bb8f0358671ea0f90af5be7: value too large for defined data type\\\"\"": unknown.
```

Note that i configured swarm stack already and the volume driver that i used is sshfs.

How can i resolve this problem ? is this about host machine kernel or something else ?

Comment: Problem seems to be linked to architecture indeed (see https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24837)
Are you running docker on windows/mac ? On a 64bits host ? 
Is your container running an x86 OS ?